# Algorithm to get lower peak of bimodal histogram

Tags: algorithms

I have a set of data, when tabulated in histogram, it looks like bimodal histogram.

[image: bimodal histogram]

With naked eyes, we can see the value for lower peak is about -1.35, however, what algorithm I can use to determine this?

Thanks.

P/s: please correct me if this is not the right place to ask this question.

Comment: this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451089/bimodal-distribution-characterization-algorithm